# Mysql update difficulty

Tags: php, mysql, referrer

I'm trying to fix my invite system. When the user log ins the system creates a `$_SESSION['id']`, the script then checks if there is any value in row `inviteid`.

If there is the system checks if the user has more points than 1000. If he has the system then updates points for the referrer using `inviteid`.

```
<?php session_start();
ob_start();
error_reporting(0);
include("dbConn.php");
?>
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
?>
<?php
   $unuserid = $_SESSION['id'];
   $sql="select * from users WHERE id = $unuserid"; 
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$unuserid'");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
    $unPOINTS = $row['points'];
    $uninviteid = $row['inviteid'];

    } 

     if(isset($uninvited)) {

     ?>

<?php
  if ($unPOINTS > 1000) {
?>
<?php
    $sql="UPDATE users SET points = $unPOINTS + 500 WHERE id = $uninviteid";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()."<br />".$sql); 
    header("Location: index.php?page=changemember&id=$UID");
}   }


?>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Get rid of `error_reporting(0);`! Do NOT hide error messages - write clean code instead.

Comment: WebnetMobile.com Thanks, I will get rid of it. Didn't really payed attention to the error_repoting(0);

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in line 26, it should read:

```
if(isset($uninviteid)) {
```

You can avoid such errors by using IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans for your development.

And try to format your PHP code using Zend coding standard, it will make your life easier. Read more on: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.html

Comment: Thanks. You really helped me. Can't believe that I changed the code hundred times and it was a tiny misspelling error. Thanks again